# Putting databases in their own Docker containers?

Tags: docker

I run a complex app with a database backend and many other things all in one container.  I notice that Docker images for different database systems are available.  When would I want to move something like a DB server to its own container, instead of running everything in the same container?  The advantage I have now is that I can deploy everything at once, and I don't have to configure more than one container to get things talking.

Comment: I think one use case would be when you want to split up your application(s) over multiple containers with a shared database. It's pretty easy to set up using docker-compose.

Answer (score 1):

`Docker` or the Container Manager is using `Linux` `container` technology to provide a best abstraction, using docker container with multiple process is a bad idea; use docker container for isolating one process, use docker volume container for storing database data ( docker state is not persistent by default).
Use docker-compose or fig to attach two docker containers db and web app, it will ease your management in future!

Comment: So as it is, I would need something like 10 docker containers to get my system working.  I want to distribute my system to users.  Won't it be overly complicated keeping one subsystem (process) per container?

Comment: Why you need 10 db container for users ?:O, try docker-compose to attach two containers

Comment: I have around 10 different services running together in this container.  They all need to be running.  If I put each process in a different container, I'd need 10 different containers for the user to run.  Postgres, Apache, on and on.

Comment: Yea you need it, and use docker compose and docker manager to manage or monitor these together